# webpack not generating source maps

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    devtool: "source-map"
}
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --colors",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server -d --watch --progress --colors"
  },
```

**index.js**

```
let h = "hello world"
console.log(h)
```

I run both `npm build` and `npm run dev` but neither seem to generate source maps. The way I'm checking if they show up is if I can see the original source in Chrome dev tools or Safari dev tools.

Thanks for any help!

**Update 0**

- Running `npm run build` (`npm build` doesn't do anything) does indeed generate `bundle.js.map` and I can use the source maps successfully in Google Chrome (yay!)
- Running `npm run dev` seems to compile fine and serves my webpage successfully but the `dist` directory doesn't contain `bundle.js` or `bundle.js.map` - but when I go to `localhost:8080` it still works (without the source maps).

Answer (score 18):

I recently had this problem with webpack 3.6.0. No source map files were being generated even though I had `devtool: 'source-map'` in webpack.config.js.

In my case, the problem was that I was passing `-d` to webpack on the command line, which is a shortcut for all of this (notice the second option and its argument):

```
--debug --devtool cheap-module-eval-source-map --output-pathinfo
```

Instead of passing `-d`, I now pass `--debug --output-pathinfo` and source map files are generated as expected.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me!
Here is shortcuts description in the docs: https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#shortcuts

Answer (score 14):

Can you see the actual `.map` files in your `dist` folder? Try adding the [SourceMapDevToolPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin/) to your `webpack.config.js` file.

```
new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
  filename: "[file].map"
}),
```

Then restart the build process and check in the `dist` folder for `.map` files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I added this plugin and when I run `webpack` it generates `bundle.js.map`. In Chrome dev tools, when I go to sources and click on `bundle.js` it says "Source map detected" but I'm not sure where to view my original source. Also, this didn't seem to work when I ran the `webpack-dev-server`. Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Interestingly, just running `webpack` (without the plugin) and setting `devtool: "source-map"` also has the same result.

Comment: In Chrome DevTools go to Sources, then at the bottom there is a cloud icon that says `web pack://`. If you hover over app.js file in your `src` folder, a label should say `app.js(from source map)`. Is this the case for you?

Comment: Yes, that is the case. If you see my reply to @HerrVoennchen it seems to generate source maps perfectly fine if I just run `webpack` but not when I run `webpack-dev-server`

Comment: @Dan It works for me! (only by removing `devtool: 'source-map'`)

Answer (score 6):

saw your question in the webpack chat. :)

change `devtool` to `source-map` and then you have source maps. In Chrome you can see the original source like this (debugging there works too)

[image]

Edit: Also in scripts in package.json you don't need to ref to the node_modules folder. just the command, npm will look automatic in the node_modules/.bin folder.

Comment: Thank you for answering! So I have set `devtool: "source-map"` but it still does not work. In Chrome, under `webpack://` I see `(webpack)`, `(webpack)-dev-server`, and `(./~)` but no `.`.

Comment: Okay, so after some more debugging I found that `npm build` doesn't do anything but `npm run build` does generate `bundle.js.map` files. And I can also see them in Chrome, thanks! So I guess I have a couple more questions - does the `.map` file *need* to be generated or are there inline source maps? Why didn't `cheap-eval-source-map` work? Why doesn't it work when using `webpack-dev-server` ?

Comment: sry for the late answer.May we should compare our webpack config and package.json scripts. something must be wrong there.Here you can look at mine. https://github.com/HerrVoennchen/dev-templates/tree/master/webpack2-react the screenshot above is from running webpack-dev-server and if you look into my webpack config there is no really dev-server specific code.Regarding the source-maps, i really have to read through the different maps available,on creating my config I just took what fitted best for me.ignore the src-folder in my repo, it doesn't match the configs anymore, I just store my configs

Answer (score 3):

I could not generate source maps, because my output.filename did not end with '.js'.

so  i need to use 'test' to set SourceMapDevToolPlugin

```
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      test: new RegExp('\.[js|css|mjs].*'),
    }),
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what my issue was, too. Such a weird behavior from Webpack...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I found:

1/ In devtool path, you use 'inline-source-map' instead 'source-map':

```
devtool:'inline-source-map',
```

2/ If u still wana use 'source-map', in plugins path, you add a new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin:

```
 plugins: [
...
new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
  test: new RegExp('\.[js|css|mjs].*')
})
```

]